# How to make rectangle on android camera using opencv?

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I want to make a rectangular box on the android camera preview using OpenCV.
results from capture only save the picture in the rectangular box in jpeg format. can give examples or simple source code using OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at some of the examples that come with OpenCV, the projects should be found within the OpenCV folder.

Regarding your question, first read a frame from the camera into a matrix, `Mat()`, then simply pass it through `rectangle(Mat img, Point pt1, Point pt2, Scalar color)`, p1 being the top left point of the rectangle you wish to draw and p2 being the bottom right point of said rectangle. If you define a `Rect()` you my also use `rect.tl()` and `rect.br()` for the coordinates

[Documentation on rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html)

Comment: Thanks @Tomme. i'll try it. but do you have source code or sample project for example? i'm very newbie on openCV.

Comment: Check out Tutorial 1 – Camera Preview and Tutorial 3 – Camera Control, you should be able find them in the OpenCV folder on your computer. This [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#running-opencv-samples) should also help if you wish to deploy these tutorials/samples to AVD.